# Putting custom error messages in Python

Tags: python, validation, python-2.7

I want to create custom error messages for a function.

```
def tr( launch_speed , launch_angle_deg , num_samples ):

#Error displays
   try:
      launch_speed>0
   except:
      raise Exception("Launch speed has to be positive!")   
   try:
      0<launch_angle_deg<90
   except:
      raise Exception("Launch angle has to be 0 to 90 degrees!")    
   try:
      um_samples = int(input())
   except:
      raise Exception("Integer amount of samples!")  
   try:
      num_samples >=2
   except:
      raise Exception("At least 2 samples!")
```

Essentially, what I want is to get an error message every time a wrong value has been written in the function variables, and I've tried creating these messages based on what I've gathered on the Internet, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"it doesn't seem to work"*? Why would you expect e.g. `launch_speed>0` to raise an error?

Comment: I'm building a function that calculates the trajectory of a projectile, so I wouldn't want launch speed to be negative

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `try: except:` for everything; for example, `launch_speed>0` **will not** raise an error for negative values. Instead, I think you want e.g.

```
if launch_speed < 0:  # note spacing, and if not try
    raise ValueError("Launch speed must be positive.")  # note specific error
```

You should also test for and raise more specific errors (see [*"the evils of `except`"*](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/)), e.g.:

```
try:
    num_samples = int(raw_input())  # don't use input in 2.x
except ValueError:  # note specific error
    raise TypeError("Integer amount of samples!")
```

You can see the list of built-in errors [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: So I tried using the second one for num_samples, but even if I input for example 5.5, I will get a result for my function and not an error.

Comment: @George you should use `raw_input`, not `input`; I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @George If you specifically want to throw an error if the user gives you a non-integer, you should do something like `user_in = raw_input(); if int(user_in) != float(user_in): raise SomeError("With a custom message")`. However it seems more useful to me to just convert it to something usable and use it, only complaining if it's not convertable to `int`

Answer (score 1):

Why not go one step further and build your own exception types? There's a quick tutorial [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions) which could be used something like:

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for exceptions defined in this module"""
    pass

class LaunchError(Error):
    """Errors related to the launch"""
    pass

class LaunchSpeedError(LaunchError):
    """Launch speed is wrong"""
    pass

class LaunchAngleError(LaunchError):
    """Launch angle is wrong"""
    pass

class SamplesError(Error):
    """Error relating to samples"""
    pass
```

In this case the default functionality of `Exception` is fine, but you may be able to get finer granularity in what you catch by defining extra exceptions.

```
if launch_speed < 0:
    raise LaunchSpeedError("Launch speed must be positive")
if 0 <= launch_angle < 90:
    raise LaunchAngleError("Launch angle must be between 0 and 90")
um_samples = input()
try:
    um_samples = int(um_samples)
except ValueError:
    raise SampleError("Samples must be an integer, not {}".format(um_samples))
if um_samples < 2:
    raise SampleError("Must include more than one sample, not {}".format(str(um_samples)))
```